# Could new users see a notification in the space where the add comment button would be, like "you need a minimum of X reputation to comment"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, comments, notifications

I just went to comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903709/how-do-i-setup-the-notepad-run-command-for-ruby/12904268#12904268), saying something like "hey thanks that solution worked for me; You know anything about extending it to [provide this feature too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212147/ruby-pry-can-i-add-something-to-the-command-pry-example-rb-so-pry-automatica)?"

I was confused why I couldn't find any sort of "add comment* button, and it took me an annoying bit of searching *just to find out why*. :/

So could us new users *see a notification* like:

> you need a minimum of X reputation to comment on questions that are not your own, and on answers that are not to your own questions

in the space where the `add comment` button *would* be?

Comment: That does indeed seem to be inconsistent with the rest of the site. Usually UI elements are still shown, even when you can't/aren't allow to use them.

Comment: @Shog9 why did you remove it, if I might ask?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: in response to a flag that I didn't check thoroughly first. [This request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123542/make-it-clearer-to-anonymous-low-rep-users-that-they-cannot-yet-add-comments) - marked as a duplicate - isn't completed; anonymous users see nothing. But users with accounts of some sort *will* see the link.

Comment: @Shog9 oops, took [that comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177881/could-new-users-see-a-notification-in-the-space-where-the-add-comment-button-wou?noredirect=1#comment612838_191343) for granted without checking, OK now. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show the "add comment" link also to users who cannot add comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144537/show-the-add-comment-link-also-to-users-who-cannot-add-comments)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - This seems a duplicate of the one you have just edited. :) Voting to close.

Comment: @hims056 yup, added my weight in. :)

Answer (score 28):

Nice idea. I suggest even better solution. Show `add comment` button to all users. If he/she is not able to add comment show them an error message on clicking that button. Something like this:

[image]

This is same as vote up/down button

> [image]

Comment: Yes, precisely. Although from an affective perspective (on the reputation explanation notification xD ), it's somewhat less unpleasant to be informed that you can't do something *before* you try it, rather than go to *try* to do something and only *then* be informed that you aren't allowed.

Comment: @Owen_R - Showing a big message under every post would not look good. Just showing a message after clicking an `add comment` button makes more sense. (IMHO)

Comment: Oh yeah, I get that perspective too. Although the big message would be just as temporary as the restriction itself... Perhaps a *short* message like `X reputation needed to add comment`, which you can click on to get a full explanation of where you can and can't?

Comment: Ah popup after first suggesting something can be clicked is bad design IMHO. It's like "Click here to do this - Nyahh nyahh you actually can't >:P" and giving the finger...

Answer (score 10):

#### Hurrah! This has been implemented now.

If you are logged in and you don't have privilege to add comments, you see a message like this:

> add comment (requires [50 reputation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment))

> [image]

"add comment" is just text (it's not a link).

Comment: This may be a causing [a related bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191280/dynamic-add-show-n-more-comments-cannot-be-clicked-when-not-logged-in)

Comment: It seems to have been removed.

Comment: Only for anon users, @Mark. Once you have an account (even an "unregistered" one), you should see it.