# Show the title character limit when writing a title

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, notifications, title, character-limit

I just ran into this while writing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177881/could-us-new-users-see-a-notification-in-the-space-where-the-add-comment-but).

[*I originally wrote:*

> *you need a minimum of X reputation to comment on questions that are not your own, and on answers that are not to your own questions*

*But had to shorten it to:*

> *you need a minimum of X reputation to comment*]

First, it didn't tell me that I'd gone over the character limit for the title until *after* I had already tabbed out of the title field.

Second, it didn't tell me how much I'd gone over or anything. I had to copy-paste the text I'd written into my text editor in order to get some real-time feedback on the exact character count, to help figure out how to best shorten it.

Comment: OT, but if you need that long a title, you're not writing a good title.

Comment: Looks like [you love long titles](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1965289/owen-r?tab=questions).

Comment: lol yes, okay, I admit that *maybe* I have a problem. xD (Regard the stellar improvement ironically just made to the title of *this* post.) Still, aint it a good idea? (This comment has `365 characters left`, it informs me below. ^^; )

Comment: (For anyone reading this later, I originally titled the question: "Instead of the popup "Title can not be longer than 150 characters", could it just tell us out limit and current count *as we write*?")

Comment: @Owen_R Yep, still think it's a reasonable idea. So I upvoted.

Comment: @Owen_R: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: @Bart Oh, and you're the one who edited my title. Props on the smooth move, man. ^^;

Comment: I upvote because I agree this could be a slight UX flaw, but indeed you should question the way you write titles if you run into such problems. I noticed that you tend to add the programming language to your title. Sometimes this is necessary for clarity, but try to avoid it and just use the tag instead.

Comment: @Mario Yes, thanks, I was actually wondering about that. Hadn't really looked much at how a question is displayed to someone looking for one to answer, on account of I aint really answering any yet, but I see now how adding the tagged language to the title is pretty redundant. (A lot of the extra length, though, comes from me being uncertain about exact terminology and trying to be very concrete.)

Answer (score 10):

The title character limit is now displayed when writing a title once the question is longer than 99 characters:

[image]