# Dynamic "add / show N more comment(s)" cannot be clicked when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

When you're not logged in and others add comments the dynamically displayed "add / show {N} more comment(s)" is not a link and cannot be activated when it was previously the non-link "add comment (requirements)".

That is the "Show {N} more comments" dynamically updates and remains a link, but the "add comment (requirements)" dynamically updates to "add / show {N} more comment(s)" and *remains not a link*.

Comment: I am getting the same behavior on the mobile version as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: @AndersUP this won't happen with Nick, he always provides juicy details about what happened, why and what he was drinking! (oh wait, that would be Oded ;))

Answer (score 1):

I see this has been "fixed" by removing the "add comment (requirements)" note entirely :-)