# Add comment link disappears after deleting a comment (mobile theme)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, mobile-web

When using the mobile theme (e.g. mobile device), the *add comment* link disappears is a comment is added and deleted.

Steps to repro:

1. Open a post (I'm using Firefox)
2. Add a comment
3. Delete the added comment

Now the *particular post* for which the comment was added & deleted, doesn't show the *add comment* link.  Reloading the post makes the link appear again, however.

First step:

> [image: Added comment]

Second step:

> [image: Deleting it]

And it's gone:

> [image: Comment deleted; add comment link disappears]

---

EDIT: This appeared to be fixed a few days back but seems to be broken again.

Comment: Reproduced while browsing the mobile version on desktop computer, Windows 7, Chrome latest stable version. This is obviously bug in the mobile theme itself, not device related.

Comment: added another comment immediately after

Comment: 100% reproduced now [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245063/deleting-comment-removes-add-comment-link-on-mobile), obviously whatever fix was in place, was rolled back

Answer (score 2):

I just pushed some fixes for [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203017/view-more-comments-link-does-not-work) [issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191280/dynamic-add-show-n-more-comments-cannot-be-clicked-when-not-logged-in), and have since been unable to reproduce this.  I'll mark this as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) just to be precise, but that doesn't mean this bug report was invalid.

Comment: Are those fixes live? Because I just reproduced it after clearing my cache.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm simply not able to reproduce this.  I tried on an iPhone with Chrome and Safari and Nexus 4 with Chrome and Firefox and it all behaved as expected.  You might have a caching issue somewhere between your device and one of our CDNs.  Without more information I don't think there's much more I can do.

Comment: I'm unable to repro the bug (as of now).

Comment: That's good news.  Probably you picked up the updates to the js.

Comment: Fixed for me too. Guess it was a caching issue somewhere. :) Thanks @Ben.