# "View more comments" link does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I noticed recently that the "view more comments" link failed to work rather often for me, usually on pages that I had opened earlier and that were open for some time. I suspect that it happens only if more comments are added after the page was loaded, but I can't be entirely sure about it. It also does not seem to happen for every case where comments are added via the live update, only if the page has been loaded for a while.

The comment link just doesn't do anything at all in these cases, I inspected the page and it looks to me as if the event listener that should be triggered is just missing entirely on the "add comment" div.

There is also [one similar bug report on meta.physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/the-add-show-1-more-comments-link-doesnt-do-anything-if-you-dont-have-comm).

Comment: Is this on a specific browser/platform?

Comment: Chrome on Windows 7

Comment: I had it happen on Safari on iOS 7.

Comment: This happens to me a lot with a few elements on the pages: viewing or adding comments, posting an answer... anything like that.  It can happen by the time I'm done reading the question or it won't happen unless the page sits for a minute.  (I am on Chrome/Windows 7.)  I have just gotten into the habit of refreshing the page before I try and do anything.  I get that little red box that says "an error occurred".

Comment: I cann't get this repro-ed. Are you on a corporate network? Any proxies? Is this a webkit only issue?

Answer (score 2):

This issue was previously reported here: [The "add / show 1 more comments" link doesn't do anything if you don't have comment permissions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5083).  Should be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Why isn't it being migrated here? Was it specific just to http://physics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: No, it's not physics-specific, but I just didn't stop to migrate.  Normally I would, but this question was already here so just linking was good enough for me.

Comment: Fair enough. What about [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192691/152859) then? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thanks for that.  I marked it as [tag:status-deferred] to be semantic and to supposedly help me remember, but it actually had the immediate effect this morning of helping me forget ;-).  I think that bug is now obsolete.