# Deleting comment removes "Add comment" link on Mobile

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

If I delete a comment on the mobile version of the site (at least if it's the only comment on an answer), the "Add comment" link will vanish along with the comment, so I have to reload to leave another comment.

[image][image]

[This bug *has* already been reported over a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197755/add-comment-link-disappears-after-deleting-a-comment-mobile-theme) but got declined as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), which is why I'm reposting this (as it may well be a new bug with the same symptoms).

I'm using Firefox 32.0.3 on Android.

Comment: Reproduced on a desktop computer with mobile theme, just click "mobile" in the footer and anyone can reproduce it.

Comment: Reproduced with Chrome 60 on mobile. Guess it's a real bug.

Comment: Still persists. Where are the devs?